# Finding gcc location

Tags: linux, gcc, debian, gcc4, g++4.8

I am on a cluster and do not have root permission, I am new to linux. I wish to run a tool with a gcc 5 version or less. My default gcc version is 6.3.0. But there is another version of gcc (gcc 4:6.3.0-4) on the system. I am trying to find its location so that I can set CC and CXX variable value to that location (e.g. export CC="/usr/bin/gcc"). I tried which gcc (it is pointing to my default gcc location) and whereis gcc.  I am not able to find the location of other gcc. It would be really helpful if someone can share the way to do it.

dpkg --list | grep compiler

> Name Version Architecture Description
>
> gcc 4:6.3.0-4 amd64 GNU C compiler
>
> gcc-6 6.3.0-18+deb9u1 amd64 GNU C compiler

My system description is as follows:

Linux b03 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: » gcc 4: **6.3.0**-4 amd64 GNU C compiler« ... and »gcc-6 **6.3.0**-18+deb9u1 amd64 GNU C compiler« are not two versions.

Answer (score 0):

Running `dpkg -L gcc 4:6.3.0-4` will give you a list of all files installed by that package. You should be able to find the executable path in there.